# Sine Wave Graph Custom X Axis and Y Axis

Tags: plotting, graphics, customization

I have the next code:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], 
  Piecewise[{{Sin[x + Pi], 0 <= x <= Pi/4}, {Sin[x + Pi], 
     Pi <= x <= 5*Pi/4}, {Sin[x + Pi], 2*Pi <= x <= 9*Pi/4}}, _], 
  Piecewise[{{Sin[x], Pi/4 <= x <= Pi}, {Sin[x], 
     5*Pi/4 <= x <= 2*Pi}, {Sin[x], 9*Pi/4 <= x <= 3*Pi}}, _]}, {x, 0,
   3 Pi}, Filling -> {2 -> Axis, 3 -> Axis}, 
 FillingStyle -> {2 -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Blue], 
   3 -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Red]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Blue, Red}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 3*Pi, Pi/2], Automatic}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"AC Voltage Supply", "Gate Voltage", 
   "Output Voltage"}]
```

The Output is the next graph:

[image]

Is it possible to do the same graph but instead of displaying on the X Axis: π/2, π, 3 π/2, 2π to display T/4, T/2, 3/4 T, T ? .. T is for Period

and in the Y Axis, instead of 1, to display Vmax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xt = Range[0, 3 Pi, Pi/2];
xticks = Transpose[{xt, xt /. Pi -> T/2}];
yticks = {{-1, "vMin"}, {-1/2, ""}, {1/2, ""}, {1, "vMax"}};
```

You can use the option

```
Ticks -> {xticks, yticks}
```

in your `plot = Plot[Sin[x],, ...]` or as

```
Show[plot, Ticks -> {xticks, yticks}]
```

[image]

Comment: good, but I think it has to be: xticks = Transpose[{xt, xt /. Pi -> T/2}];

Comment: @DieDauphin, right. Fixed now.